# Easy Derivation for the 2nd order Approximation of a two variable function seems wrong

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

I thought about a way to simply explain the 2nd order approximation of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ around a point $(x_0,y_0)$.

First we take the linear approximation of $f$:

$$f(x,y) \approx  f(x_0,y_0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \Delta y $$

where all the partial derivatives are evaluated at $(x_0,y_0)$ and $\Delta x = x- x_0$, $\Delta y = y - y_0$.

Then I thought that for the second order approximation, we approximate the partial derivative themself with a first order approximation:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) \approx  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x} \cdot \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y \partial x} \cdot \Delta y $$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \approx  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \cdot \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{ \partial^2 y} \cdot \Delta y $$

And then putting this in the approximation of $f(x,y)$ we would get:

$$f(x,y) \approx  f(x_0,y_0) + \left[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x} \cdot \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y \partial x} \cdot \Delta y \right] \cdot \Delta x + \left[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \cdot \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{ \partial^2 y} \cdot \Delta y \right] \cdot \Delta y \\
=  f(x_0,y_0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \Delta y + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x } \cdot \Delta x^2 + 2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \cdot \Delta x \Delta y + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 y} \cdot \Delta y^2
$$

But the real formula is
$$
f(x,y) \approx f(x_0,y_0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \Delta y + \frac{1}{2} \left(  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x } \cdot \Delta x^2 + 2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \cdot \Delta x \Delta y + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 y} \cdot \Delta y^2 \right)
$$

Where si my reasoning wrong? Can it be corrected to get to the correct result or is it completely wrong?

Comment: Test it with a single variable function like $f(x)=x^2$ to see what goes wrong.

Comment: The root cause of your error is that in the first order approximation the partial derivatives are evaluated at the point $(x_0,y_0)$. Not at the point $(x,y)$ as you seem to do, when you approximate the first order partial derivatives! To get a better approximation you need to approximate $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ at a half-way point. Compare with the mean value theorem!

Comment: In other words, start from
$$f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\frac{x+x_0}2,y)\Delta x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,\frac{y+y_0}2)\Delta y,$$
or some similar formula, where you first fix one coordinate then the other. Both using single variable function approximations.